# jquery mobile mixed data-roles for lists?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

With jQuery Mobile, is it possible to have a mixed list?  That is, 3 item list.  First 2 would be collapsible while the last would be listview?

I understand I can create two different divs.  One to handle the collapsibles and another to handle the listview (the listview li item is an external link).  But I'd like the three list items to be grouped together in the UI (so it doesn't look totally separate).

Is this possible?